# increasing productivity - mastering a language vs. selecting efficient tools

Tags: programming-languages, c++, python, perl

I'm looking for advice from experienced developers on this question.

In my work there's a need for a lot of one-off code. It's tempting to just dip into the right python/perl library calls to do these little tasks as quickly as possible.

I used to be of the philosophy of - "use most efficient tool for the task". However, I'm afraid that over time, this means that I won't have a deeper experience and expertise, so recently I've been forcing myself to use C++ (w/ Boost and STL) for everything, even if I could do the task in python or perl much more quickly. I'm hoping that in the long run, this will make me a more productive developer. I hope to reach a level of familiarity that I can do things in C++ as quickly as I can in python (and also have the practice to work on bigger projects that would require C++).

Is this a good strategy towards long-term productivity and deeper skills? Or am I unnecessarily wasting time / torturing myself?

Comment: "do things in C++ as quickly as I can in python" -- Good luck. Try a 0815 web application, for instance. Learning another language is certainly a good goal, and won't hurt. But it's not mutually exclusive with choosing appropriate tools - quite the contrary, one big reason learning several languages is good is that none of them is perfect for all tasks.

Comment: there are limits to this practice of course. At the moment many of the programs I write are data analysis pipelines that are at least feasible in any language, but perhaps easier/quicker if I use perl/python. I can still do them in C++ within a reasonable amount of time, but in the short-term it does take more time. The question is if it's worth it in the long-term in terms of both skills, productivity (and possibly career opportunities...)

Comment: Doing things in a less efficient way is a skill I'm glad I haven't mastered.

Answer (score 9):

> Or am I unnecessarily wasting time / torturing myself?

That's what you are probably doing.

A woodworker doesn't spend all day using a chisel to cut out shapes instead of a saw, does he? Programming languages are tools just like libraries and development environments. Writing a big C++ program to perform a job best handled by perl or grep is often a waste of time.

But, don't go overboard on the ["best tool for a job" religion](http://headrush.typepad.com/creating_passionate_users/2006/08/when_the_best_t.html). A tool your are very familiar with and enjoy using may well exceed it's drawbacks compared to a "proper" tool that you don't enjoy using.

Comment: Maybe I didn't quite use the right tone. I actually do enjoy using C++ (especially vs. Perl :) and find it stimulating so that is part of it.

Answer (score 2):

I thinks devs often find the grass greener on the other side. There isn't much that can't be theoretically be accomplished in either environment. But, the strengths of C++ become clearer when dealing with performance-intensive problems, while the strengths of scripting become clearer when dealing with breadth-first implementation. At some point, the productivity curves meet, and switchover to C++ makes its case.

Also, C++ is the lingua franca of development for historical reasons, and obviously C++ talks best with C++, so you're likely to encounter it frequently.

Finally, learning both sides is great for perspective, which generally makes one a more versatile and informed developer. So, I think improving your C++ would be a very productive thing for you, and learning something like Python (or Perl, etc) is a great thing for C++ developers to know.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful perspective. In terms of exposure, I'm sort of past the point of exposure-to-basic-ideas/usage - the question at this point is how to best invest my time/effort now beyond that "exposure" level of familiarity. My feeling is there is more depth to discover in C++ - getting comfortable with STL/Boost and sharpening a coherent coding style, so in part, that's part of the knowledge I'm pursuing by forcing myself to use it all the time.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to assume that - I agree with you that there's a lot more depth to discover. I think it is worthwhile to force usage as practice, though I'd temper that if you find yourself working with others who might not be on the same page. Myself, I try to stick with what I know, and venture out a little at a time. I've tried pursuing depth, but found only a small fraction actually sticks with me. I suppose it's a function of ones environment.

Answer (score 1):

Using many languages and tools **increase the ability of a programmer to think beyond a particular language**. If someone sticks to C alone, that person will code strings every time there is a need for a string. Not bad, but counter-productive.
Let me write from a different perspective. I have seen that computer science/engineering students turned programmers approach coding a solution different than others. They do not think of what is available in the language, but start from a generic solution and try to find ways to code it in a language. This is the concept of design before coding.
I believe your question can be answered from the same perspective. Using many different languages and tools to solve a problem **enables one to realize there are ways to solve a problem beyond the traditional way**, and one tries to **find such constructs/libraries** in every language. I believe this is an invaluable quality of a programmer that can only be built by working in different languages.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to truly master a language is to use it regularly on real projects.  Forcing yourself to use a language for one-offs is great when you are enthusiastic about it, but the novelty usually wears off before you really achieve mastery.  Not that just being "familiar" with a language isn't useful in and of itself.

Answer (score 0):

"use most efficient tool for the task" - don't completely throw away this principle. You won't be able to achieve the same level of efficiency in C++ as in Python and Perl, simply because they are high-level languages. But there will be reasons you will want to choose C++ in spite of development efficiency.

But, by all means, do choose C++ over the others for the sake of practicing it. Getting familiar with it is a good start, and won't be a waste of time. But note that there will be limitations to how proficient you can get by writing the C++ equivalent of a script. You'll eventually need to move beyond that to actually get proficient.